# Dynamically created eventhandler event is not firing in multiview

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to an add event handler to an image button in one of my view of multi view control. But the event handler is not firing. But if bind the buttons in page load then the event handler is firing. Can Anyone help?

```
LinkButton lnkButton = new LinkButton();
lnkButton.Click += new EventHandler(CButtonClickHandlerNew);
```

This is how I added the event handler.

Comment: It is hard to predict the issues without seeing the code that you are using

Comment: I have modified the question by adding the code

Comment: And how are we supposed to help you with two lines of code? yes this looks right, there shouldnt be a problem with these lines....

Comment: the given code looks fine, there may some other reasons. by the way what type of application is this? asp?winforms? use proper tags

Comment: This is asp application. Bthe above code is written in a function which is called only when the particular view is to be displayed

Comment: Impossible to answer with this little code, that LinkButton is created dynamically but not event added to any parent control. So I guess there is alot more code that can and will affect whether that event will trigger or not.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following code to call the event of dynamically created button

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  if(!IsPostBack)
  {
     placeHolder.Controls.Add(CreateButton());
  }  
}

public Button CreateButton()
{
   Button btn = new Button();
   btn.ID = "id";
   btn.Text = "some text";
   btn.Click += btn_Click;
   return btn;
}

private void btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
}
```